# JavaScript, what is "binde" means, not "bind"? document.binde.tagname...?

Tags: javascript

I have in my JS code, some lines with `binde`, what is it?  Why is it working and what does it mean?

On example with, `type="checkbox"`:

```
if (document.binde.nameofthecheckbox.checked)
{
    //...its true whens checked and do the code
}
```

or

```
somevar = document.binde.somehtmltagname.value;
```

`somevar` gets the value of "somehtmltagname"

No one can answer me, I only heard "never seen something like that before".  I would be happy to know what it is, and not only using it because it works.

Comment: It's probably something that comes from the rest of the code on the page, which only you can see.

Comment: `binde` is not a standard property of `document`. Perhaps it's added to `document` somewhere else in your code.

Comment: This `binde` seems like a custom-added property, it's not a standard one.  Maybe some sort of DOM library (like jQuery or something)?

Comment: Search all of your code/libraries for `binde`

Comment: Odds are you have `<form id="binde">` somewhere.

Comment: Welcome to old school reference forms and form fields.

Comment: Quentin ur right , i didt see that , its not my html so, what a waste of time sorry for that question and thank you

Comment: I thought about "bind" as i have seen that and bind has nothing to do whit document, so sorry for that question and thank you, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not well known, but `document` might define HTML elements with `id` specified as `document[HTMLElement.ID]` as such, if there is an `<input id="binde">` on the page, it will point to that.

If not, try logging it:

```js
console.log(document.binde)
```

Comment: probably a name and not an id.

Comment: Elements' `id`s get added to `window` not `document`.  If you had `<input id="binde">`, then you could access that element as `window.binde` (not `docuement.binde`).